# give my compare function a relative point as parameter

Tags: python, sorting, compare

I have a graph class that has nodes that are on a 2d grid.
I want to sort the nodes in graph by comparing to a relative point, called end, using a compare function.
I want to be able to compare inside the function, but I am struggling to understand how I can pass the relative point to the compare function.

My code:

```
class Graph:
  def __init__(self, end):
    self.nodes = set()
    self.edges = defaultdict(list)
    self.distances = {}
    self.end = end
  def add_node(self, value):
    self.nodes.add(value)

  def add_edge(self, from_node, to_node, distance):
    self.edges[from_node].append(to_node)
    self.edges[to_node].append(from_node)
    self.distances[(from_node, to_node)] = distance

  def compare(node1, node2):

      d1 = findDist(end, node1)
      d2 = findDist(end, node2)
      if d1 < d2:
          return -1
      elif d1 > d2:
          return 1
      else:
        return 0

  def sortPoints(self):
        sorted(self.edges, key=self.compare)
```

So a compare function usually gets 2 parameters and the built in sorted function knows how to use it. I thought using the relative point as  a class member, but again I couldn't find a way to give my compare function the self keyword, and access it.

Is there any good way to achieve this goal?

Comment: I can't test it currently, but you might want to look into lambda expressions of the type `sorted(self.edges, key=lambda x: self.compare(*x))`  (if I understood it correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use the return value of `findDist` as a key you could make `findDist` a method of `Graph`. Then you could pass it as `key` parameter to sorted: `sorted(self.edges, self.findDist)`. Here's a simplified example on how it would work:

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, end):
        self.end = end

    def find_dist(self, x):
        return abs(self.end - x)

    def sort_values(self, it):
        return sorted(it, key=self.find_dist)

g = Graph(10)
print(g.sort_values(range(5, 15)))
```

Output:

```
[10, 9, 11, 8, 12, 7, 13, 6, 14, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Must sorted be returned or could it just be used to sort the class member ?

Comment: @Sharonica `sorted` returns a sorted copy of an iterable but you don't have to return it from calling method. It seems that you're sorting keys of `defaultdict` so you need create a sorted copy of the keys since dicts are unsorted but you don't need to return it from `sortPoints`.